# How do you say “highest quality” or “first class” in French?

Tags: vocabulaire

Not necessarily the literal translation, but something like the idiomatic “top shelf” in English.

Comment: Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Did you using the phrase in a sentence in DeepL? :  [I only buy top shelf products](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/I%20only%20buy%20top%20shelf%20products).

Comment: @None Madame, revenez svp., on a besoin de vous ! Salutations.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the phrase [*haut de gamme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haut_de_gamme). Note that "haut" is used here as a noun and not as an adjective.

> Ce magasin ne vend que des produits haut de gamme.

Comment: or "de luxe" (in 2 words). Maybe a bit more dated

Comment: "De luxe" is more about the price imho.

Comment: I think "de luxe" is associated to some industries like clothes, bags, shoes, cars,... as one can guess, it literally means "luxury". I would not use "de luxe" for a cellphone for example.

Answer (score 5):

J'aime bien le désuet *[Nec plus ultra](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nec_plus_ultra)*.

Answer (score 0):

« **De qualité supérieure** » est un choix standard qu'il faut apprendre -- comme tout autre terme (voir les autres réponses) -- à utiliser idiomatiquement, mais il est assez « passe partout » ([Le parisien](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/qualit%C3%A9%20sup%C3%A9rieure/fr-fr/).

- des articles/ de la marchandise/des produits/des vins/… de qualité supérieure

« **De première qualité** »  est un synonyme.

- des légumes/de la confiserie/de l'habillement/… de première qualité

Answer (score 0):

"Crème de la crème" ou encore "C'est le top du top." Tout dépend du contexte et de familiarité entre interlocuteurs.